# EF. Delete entity by Id that has foreign key

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have two tables `Job (Id, Title)` and `Employee (Id, Name, JobId)`.  1-* relationship.

How can I delete Employee that has reference to it's job without retrieving information from the database?

I can do something like that:

```
var j = new Job { Id = 1 };  // UGLY, I have to create and attach Job instance and job.Id should be exactly the same as id  employee entity reffers to (!) 
e = new Employee { Id = 1, Job = j };  
db.AttachTo("Jobs", e);
db.AttachTo("Employees", e);
db.DeleteObject(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

but I want to have something like :

```
e = new Employee { Id = 1 };  
db.AttachTo("Employees", e);
db.DeleteObject(e);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Is it possible to construct entity and delete it by id without populating the reference? Attach/Delete approach  works ok if entity scheme has no foreign keys

Comment: Why can't you use second approach? What version of EF do you use?

Comment: Thank you for the question - I'll check it in a dew days. It's MSVS 2008 Express with 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 2):

In EF you need first to load the item, in order to delete it.

You could write a stored procedure to delete an item by id, and then call the stored procedure from EF.

Comment: Yes, you are completely right. But I want to avoid additional roundtrip to database.

Comment: If you implement it using the stored procedure you save the round trip, as long as you have the id of the item that you want to delete.